# How to access a VBA Userform Button control code programmatically

Tags: excel, vba

I want whenever I click on my ActiveX command button on Sheet1 it open VBA Editor and jump directly to the code I wrote for a button on my userform. I know the way to jump directly to code for a module but I couldn't find a property for userform button control (something like ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1").Controls("MyButton"))

Following is my code for jumping right into my Madule1 code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim Wb As Workbook: Set Wb = ThisWorkbook

'---Open Module1
Application.VBE.MainWindow.Visible = True
Wb.VBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1").Activate

End Sub
```

I thaught these pictures would help to better understand my goal:

1-I have an ActiveX command button on sheet1

[image]

2-I have userform with a commandbutton on it

[image]

3-This commandbuttun has it's own code which I want to jump to it's code

[image]

Comment: Try `Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1").CodeModule.CodePane.Show`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to jump to that specific sub directly, try this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("UserForm1").CodeModule.CodePane.Show

With Application.VBE.ActiveCodePane.CodeModule
    lStartLine = .ProcStartLine("CommandButton1_Click", 0) '"CommandButton1_Click" being the name of the sub you want.
    .CodePane.SetSelection lStartLine, 1, lStartLine, 1
End With

End Sub
```

First line should show you the code panel for the userform, and the second part selects the row down by the sub you are looking for by name.